# Listview image repeat from server in row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-webview, universal-image-loader

in my list view on android when scroll images(lazy loading) are uploaded to repeat the first two. 
Photos are uploaded from an online server
In addition, on android 4.4 the pictures are very very big. 
Why? solutions?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        Log.d(TAG, "POS: " + position);         

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_posts, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvTitolo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitoloPost);
            holder.tvData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvData);
            holder.ivPost = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPost);
            holder.tvContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            holder.tvExcerpt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvExcerpt);
            holder.wvPost = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wvPost);
            holder.tvIDPost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvIDPost);
            holder.tvUrlPost = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvURLPost);
            holder.tvCommPost = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCommPost);
             convertView.setTag(holder);             
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }final Post post = getItem(position);            
        holder.tvTitolo.setText(post.getTitle());
        holder.tvData.setText(post.getDate());      
        WebSettings webSettings = holder.wvPost.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        holder.wvPost.setFocusable(false);
        holder.wvPost.setClickable(false);
        holder.wvPost.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        holder.wvPost.setLongClickable(false);
holder.wvPost.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        holder.wvPost.loadUrl(post.getThumbnail());
        Log.v(TAG, "html: <!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src= " + post.getThumbnail() + " alt=\"\"></body></html>");
        holder.wvPost.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src= " + post.getThumbnail() + " alt=\"\"></body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        holder.wvPost.setClickable(false);

    if (post.getThumbnail().equals("null")) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(null, holder.ivPost);
        }else {
            imageLoader.displayImage(post.getThumbnail(), holder.ivPost);
        }        
        Log.d(TAG, "THUMB: " + post.getThumbnail());            
        /* if(post.getThumbnail().equals("null")){
            holder.ivPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            imageLoader.displayImage(post.getThumbnail(), holder.ivPost);
            holder.ivPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
        }*/

        imageLoader.displayImage(post.getThumbnail(), holder.ivPost);

        holder.tvExcerpt.setText(post.getExcerpt());
        holder.tvContent.setText(post.getContent());
        holder.tvIDPost.setText(post.getId());
        holder.tvUrlPost.setText(post.getThumbnail());

        String comments = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < post.getmComments().size(); i++) {
            comments = "<b>" + post.getmComments().get(i).getName() + 
                        "</b><br>" + 
                        post.getmComments().get(i).getContent() + 
                        "<br><b>on </b>" + 
                        post.getmComments().get(i).getDate() + 
                        "<br><br>";
        }           
        holder.tvCommPost.setText(comments);                        
        return convertView;
    }}
```

XML row_post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitoloPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Titolo"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTitoloPost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitoloPost"
        android:text="Data" />

     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/wvPost"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvData"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:background="#ffffff"

          />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" 
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExcerpt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/wvPost"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wvPost"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIDPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvContent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvURLPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvIDPost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvContent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCommPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvURLPost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvContent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share the R.layout.row_posts .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have cached images. Delete the data with the Application Manager and launch again.

**EDITED:** Be sure that you call just once displayImage method inside getView:

Evoid using comparisons with null with equals:

```
if (post.getThumbnail().equals("null"))
```

Instead, use as follows:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(post.getThumbnail()))
```

Finally:

```
//!TextUtils.isEmpty performs 2 checks: 1) Object!=null 2) Is not an empty String
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(post.getThumbnail())) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(post.getThumbnail(), holder.ivPost);
}
// No more callings to displayImage!!
```

Comment: Ok, then delete superflous code:

imageLoader.displayImage(post.getThumbnail(), holder.ivPost);

You are calling always twice for each instance of getview.. after that check the log:

Log.d(TAG, "THUMB: " + post.getThumbnail()); 

Check that the url is repeating or not for each position. Also, please post your getItem(position) code

Comment: I commented the code inside the else, the situation is somewhat improved. However, in a few nanoseconds take more pictures instead of uploading that soon. 

I did not understand what should I post?

Comment: Post these stuffs: 1)The code of getItem(int position) method. 2)Log report generated by Log.d(TAG, "THUMB: " + post.getThumbnail());

Comment: POS: 0
html: <!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = "text-align:center"><img src= hurl img  alt=""></body></html>
THUMB: url img 
POS: 1
html: <!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = "text-align:center"><img src= url img alt=""></body></html>
THUMB: url img 
POS: 2
V/app(11581): html: <!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = "text-align:center"><img src= url img  alt=""></body></html>
D/app(11581): THUMB: url img 
I/chromium(11581): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
D/app(11581): POS: 0
POS: 1
etc…

Comment: I've edited your code: http://pastebin.com/w156Fkna
Basically i've changed when you call displayImage (called once): 
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(post.getThumbnail())) {
 imageLoader.displayImage(post.getThumbnail(), holder.ivPost);
}

Comment: What you posted as Log is not exactly what i suggested you to do, i did mean that in Eclipse you have a Window which show that Log under the name LogCat, which prints what you want in a line of code, in our case: Log.d(TAG, "THUMB: " + post.getThumbnail()); the results should be a lot of lines with the pattern: "TAG", "THUMB"+ urlImageDisplayedAtPosition

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48851/discussion-between-devokand-and-billyjoker)